# How to use zapi for zephyr jira

Tags: jira-zephyr

I want to create an automated process for my tests. I am using jira and zapi. I want to try interacting with my tests in zephyr-jira using postman api. The thing is there isn't much documentation on how to use zapi.

First thing, what is the url? Is it `test.atlassian.net/jira/?/?/?/apifunction?`

Second thing, I can generate an access key and secret key but it seems like I also need an authorization jwt token, how can I generate one that I can use via postman?

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

The apiary documentation is here  https://getzephyr.docs.apiary.io/#
That will help you assemble the requests.  What the requests and responses actually represent is still confusing (to me, anyway).

In postman:  `https://{{JiraHost}}/rest/zapi/latest/`

some examples:

```
https://{{JiraHost}}/rest/zapi/latest/cycle/830
https://{{JiraHost}}/rest/zapi/latest/cycle?versionId=21689
```